# SUMO Internal Edge

Tags: sumo

I have run the quick start tutorial of SUMO and it is working fine (https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Tutorials/quick_start.html).

I want to understand the purpose of Internal edge as it is not touched in the quick start tutorial, though mentioned in the tutorial code on github:
(https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/master/tests/complex/tutorial/quickstart/data/quickstart.net.xml).

I have read the internal edge details: https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Networks/SUMO_Road_Networks.html#internal_edges

My question is:

1. What is the benefit of using internal edge?
2. Do we have to define internal edges manually as I couldn't find option in netedit (i have latest version)
3. Is it always required to define internal edge.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally received an answer from sumo's mailing list:

Please check if the option „internal-links” in netedit is enable or not. You can do that by going to “processing” in the tool bar, then “Options” - > “junction”. The option “no internal links” should NOT be selected. Below you can find two images with the steps. After you have done this, try to save the network again and the internal edges should be added.

The github link you have sent (https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/master/tests/complex/tutorial/quickstart/data/quickstart.net.xml) is a sumo Network file. In this file you can find the elements of the network: nodes, edges, etc. See SUMO_Road_Networks.html (https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Networks/SUMO_Road_Networks.html) for more information about sumo networks.

Your two question are answered in the link I sent you (See internal_links (https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Intersections.html#internal_links) for information about simulating with/without internal edges or links). Internal links and internal edges are the same thing.

Regards,